# Knot invariants in WZW CFT via Holographic Principle

Tags: knot-theory, duality, topological-quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

In the physics literature the Holographic Principle relates
theories in the bulk and the theories in the asymptotic boundary.
While the bulk theory is the 3D Chern-Simons theory, the
corresponding boundary theory is the WZW CFT. I am not sure how
complete the correspondence is, so I decide to test if the Wilson
loop observables of 3D Chern-Simons (knot invariants) in the bulk
can be computed in the WZW model. I am actually in doubt of this
because how could you ever project a general knot to the boundary
without losing information? Extra data (e.g. up/down crossing)
must be "remembered" on the boundary, **and I'm curious how that
would be implemented on the CFT side.**

One relevant work is [1], whose abstract promises such a
construction in terms of gauge invariant composites of 2D WZW
field. However, the work only works with $M^{3} = S^{2} \times S^{1}$. It does
not pass to the asymptotic boundary, but instead it works with
each piece of S^{2} instead. And, in the end, it only checks the
results for trivial knots.

#### Questions

1. How complete is the correspondence in this case (3DCS/2DWZW)?
2. Where to find a detailed correspondence between the two
   theories; in particular, a formula for link invariants on the
   CFT side.

#### Reference

- [1] [Explicit connection between conformal field theory and 2+1 Chern-Simons theory by Daniel C. Cabra and Gerardo L. Rossini](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9506054.pdf)

Comment: I think that questions about holography are better suited for Physics.SE, so probably better to try there

Comment: I seem to remember that Costello--Witten--Yamazaki look at Wilson loops in (4d?) Chern--Simons are relate it to quantum integrable vertex models, as an upgrade (with spectral parameters, i.e. affine case) of Witten's old paper about Chern--Simons and the Jones polynomial. Is that perhaps relevant or interesting for you?

Comment: I'm unsure about specifics, but the picture I have in my mind is that one should draw a knot as braid diagram and then stretch them to intersect the boundary. Then to each topological line operator in the bulk one assigns a point vertrex operator in the boundary CFT. The observables then should be some conformal blocks with such insertions.

Comment: @NikitaGrygoryev How is the braid information implemented on the CFT side?